# Unable to install Scipy latest version 1.9.3 on python3.8-alpine image

Tags: docker, scikit-learn, scipy, python-3.8, alpine-linux

Trying to install Scipy latest version (1.9.3) on python3.8-alpine image

```
tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.8-alpine
```

is not successful.

Scipy tries to install numpy 1.8.5 and it fails with following error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Log' from 'distutils.log' (/tmp/pip-build-env-28q9f6x4/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/log.py)
```

I can goahead and install lower version of scipy. But I am having issue with Sklearn

While trying to install sklearn, it tries to install latest scipy and it fails.

Is there a way i can enforce scipy version to be installed for sklearn

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with alpine and python.

This [article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/) shows that alpine images should not be used with python as it:

- Make your builds much slower.
- Make your images bigger.
- On occassion, introduce obscure runtime bugs.

I think that your problem comes from the fact that alpine image does not handle wheels files properly.

I would recommend you to switch from `python:3.8-alpine` to `python:3.8-slim`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from setuptools. Pin to a version less than 65. Scipy should build on Alpine from source without issue. One of the scipy continuous integration tests checks this. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/ci/cirrus_general_ci.yml#L40.